# My codes works but I am wondering where I can improve the code, what can you suggest?

Tags: excel, vba

My code runs pretty quick. I've decided to use FSO as I'll be opening and reading several large files during execution of this code. My code already runs pretty fast but I'm wondering what I could do to improve it.

I have already turned of screen updating, aside from turning on manual calculations (not part of the scope of this project) what could I do?

```
Row = 2

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

'Paths
serverPath = "\\kingnet\public\reports\"

'Files
lcaseReport = "Slbs_a01.txt"
dcaseReport = "Dlbs_a01.txt"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheet2

    Do While .Cells(Row, 3) <> ""

        If (Cells(Row, 7)) = Date Then
            filePath = serverPath
        ElseIf (Cells(Row, 7)) < Date Then
            filePath = serverPath & "archive\" & Format(.Cells(Row, 7), "mmddyyyy") & "\"
        ElseIf (Cells(Row, 7)) = "" Then
            GoTo Skip
        End If

        If .Cells(Row, 8) = "" Then
            Set fsoStream = FSO.OpenTextFile(filePath & lcaseReport, ForReading)

            Do While fsoStream.AtEndOfStream <> True
                strLine = fsoStream.ReadLine
                carton = Mid(strLine, 10, 16)

                'lcase First Label
                If carton = .Cells(Row, 3).Value = True Then
                    .Cells(Row, 8).Value = Mid(strLine, 31, 5)
                    .Cells(Row, 11).Value = Mid(strLine, 41, 5)
                    .Cells(Row, 13).Value = "lcase"
                End If

                'lcase Last Label
                If carton = .Cells(Row, 4).Value = True Then
                    .Cells(Row, 8).Value = Mid(strLine, 31, 5)
                    .Cells(Row, 12).Value = Mid(strLine, 41, 5)
                    .Cells(Row, 14).Value = .Cells(Row, 12).Value - .Cells(Row, 11).Value
                End If
            Loop

            fsoStream.Close
            Set FSO = Nothing
        End If

Skip:
        Row = Row + 1
    Loop

End With

'dcase
Row = 2

With Sheet2

    Do While .Cells(Row, 3) <> ""

        If (Cells(Row, 7)) = Date Then

            filePath = serverPath

        ElseIf (Cells(Row, 7)) < Date Then

            filePath = serverPath & "archive\" & Format(.Cells(Row, 7), "mmddyyyy") & "\"

        Else
            GoTo Skip2
        End If

        If .Cells(Row, 13) = "" Then
            Set fsoStream = FSO.OpenTextFile(filePath & dcaseReport, ForReading)
            Do While fsoStream.AtEndOfStream <> True
                strLine = fsoStream.ReadLine
                carton = Mid(strLine, 10, 16)

                'dcase First Label
                If carton = .Cells(Row, 3).Value = True Then
                    .Cells(Row, 8).Value = Mid(strLine, 31, 5)
                    .Cells(Row, 11).Value = Mid(strLine, 41, 5)
                    .Cells(Row, 13).Value = "dcase"
                End If

                'dcase Last Label
                If carton = .Cells(Row, 3).Value = True Then
                    .Cells(Row, 8).Value = Mid(strLine, 31, 5)
                    .Cells(Row, 12).Value = Mid(strLine, 41, 5)
                    .Cells(Row, 14).Value = .Cells(Row, 12).Value - .Cells(Row, 11).Value
                End If
            Loop

            fsoStream.Close
            Set FSO = Nothing
        End If

Skip2:
        Row = Row + 1
    Loop

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
Select Case Err.Number
    Case 76
    MsgBox "Archive folder for date " & (Cells(Row, 7)) & " on row number " & Row & " missing. Contact Server Ops. To skip this line click ignore.", vbAbortRetryIgnore + vbDefaultButton3

    Resume Skip

    Case 53

    MsgBox "File missing from " & filePath & ". Files may be archived, run again after midnight or contact Server Ops.", vbAbortRetryIgnore + vbDefaultButton3

    Resume Skip
End Select
```

Comment: For code review, have a look [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think your question is better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You've including a `With` clause but are not using it in instances such as `(Cells(Row, 7))`

Comment: Thanks, will post this there. Tim, I'm curious how it knows I'm talking about sheet2  when using (Cells(Row, 7)) instead of .Cells(Row, 7))... could this cause potential issues if another worksheet is active while the code runs?

Comment: Yes @Zakth that is why you need to reference your sheet/workbook objects, it will work allright until someone clicks another sheet while the macro is running. You referenced it, but never used the reference.

Comment: @Damian thanks, not actually sure why I ended up doing it that way... took me awhile to  figure out the looping for this code... still fairly new to VBA. I'll definitely change that to prevent possible issues.

Comment: Using select Case rather than multiple IF, ElseIf's would be slightly quicker given you are interrogating  .cells(row,7)  in each instance. The Case would only lookup Row and contents of cells(row,7) once, while potentially the if's would look it up three times